# What’s a good way to deal with a german keyboard when using Emacs on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard

Maybe it’s a bit weird to ask this question in English because my problem is a rather non-English one. I’m an Mac OS X user and I’m on my way to learning Emacs. I decided to use the Emacs 23.1 Cocoa build that by default uses the Mac keyboard’s alt/option key as the meta key. But because I am German and I’m using a German keyboard, of course, it get’s quite tricky to enter parantheses that are needed for programming extensively: `{` `}` `[` `]`

To get these characters on the German keyboard layout you have to press the following keys:

```
alt-5 for '['
alt-8 for '{'
```

which translate according to the situation described above to

```
M-5
M-8
```

both running the command `digit-argument` in Emacs.

I’m not really sure how to get around this issue. I know that you can change the actual key that should be used as the meta key (e.g. I could change the meta key to be the command key). But I think that every choice will come at a cost and have some obvious disadvantages as it “overrides” some predefined OS behaviour that may be needed while editing with a foreign language keyboard.

For now, the best option to me seems to be to use the CAPS LOCK key as the meta key as this choice doesn’t interfere with pre-existing key combinations.

What are your experiences concerning this issue? Do you (non-English) use an English keyboard (layout) while coding? Don’t you get mixed up with such context dependent keyboard layouts? Or do there exists some best practices which key to use as meta key on a German or similar keyboard? Or even some configuration options?

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 7):

With a bit of practice, you can mentally switch back and forth between a US and DE keyboard layout -- even the swapped Y and Z become second nature after a while. I did that for years while working in Germany.

But even with a US keyboard layout, there are still characters that you can't enter without Alt. I personally use Command as Meta for this reason, leaving Alt/Option for the built-in OS X dead-keys, e.g. "alt-shift-2" => €, "alt-e e" => é:

```
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta
        mac-option-modifier 'none
        default-input-method "MacOSX")
```

Another option would be to relocate "problem" keys like { } using the keyboard-translate function.

Comment: This works awesome! If you want to have a "real" ISO german keyboard, then you can also install the corresponding keyboard layout, see http://codewut.de/content/pc-keyboard-layout-mac-german . If you are able to touch type blindly then you can also switch cmd with alt and you have almost a normal german keyboard.

Comment: Personally (with a Swedish/Finnish keyboard) I find it useful to set the mac-right-option-modifier to 'none, but leave the left one as 'meta. Then I can use the right Alt key to get those brackets etc, and the left one works as a meta key. Which is nice, if one is already used or can get used to that.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but I just switched to mac and had similar problems (Albeit with a Danish keyboard layout).

From the menu select `Options` -> `Option, Command, Meta keys` -> `Right Option is Meta`. You can now use the right Alt key as meta, whereas the left Alt key is left untouched. Eg. you can use it to type "unusual" characters (Which may not be so unusual, if you're a programmer).

There is also a selection of `... Meta & German` (And other langiages), which might work for you. Alas there is no selection for Danish, so I'll have to stick with `Right Option is Meta`

Answer (score 2):

You can press "Command ;" to change the option key between being the meta key and being the normal option key.  I believe you can even do this in the middle of a key sequence.  When I need to enter diacritics into Emacs, I just press "Command ;" rather than use the various input modes in Emacs.  You can also access the setting through Options -> Option -> Option key is Meta.

The other option is to rebind keys in your .emacs file.

Speaking of switching keyboard layouts, I switch between Dvorak and US Qwerty often enough that it doesn't bother me, and they are much more different than the US and German layouts.  (Dvorak reduces hand strain for me).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344389/osx-emacs-unbind-just-the-right-alt). It recommends using this in your emacs config

```
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil)
```

to reset emacs' default behavior for the right alt/option key. This keeps emacs from reacting to this key, allowing the OS to deal with it the way it normally would.

I found this to be a good solution because it's consistent with the solution that people at my job implemented in iTerm to allow them to have both access to []{}|\ and also take advantage of the bash command line navigation bindings like alt/meta-f, -b, -d, and so on.

In short, by using this configuration, the only pain I had to suffer was getting used to using right-alt for []{}|\ and so on, and left-alt for emacs commands.

Lastly, the above link was specific to Aquamacs, but I can confirm that the vanilla emacs install for for Homebrew also supports the option.

Comment: This is also consistent with "standard" german keyboard layout(i.e. windows), where the right "alt-gr" gives you []{}|\ and the left "alt" works out of the box for emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Aquamacs (http://aquamacs.org/) is a mac-friendly version of Emacs. They have a Preview (and nightlies) based on Cocoa and Emacs 23.1.

Aquamacs has the option to rebind option command and meta in various stages between native mac keybindings and native emacs bindings. You should be able to find a stage that suits your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

This really is an old question. However, I faced this too and there is another solution: rebind the keys in question.

I did not want to swap `meta` and `cmd` (aka `super`) keys since

- IMHO emacs supports the standard mac bindings (e.g. `cmd-s` for save) pretty well and
- the `cmd` key remains available for personal shortcuts (e.g. I like to kill a buffer with `cmd-w`)

Here is a config snippet to rebind the keys only when running on a mac:

```
(if (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (progn
    ;; "fix" the broken keyboard
    (global-set-key "\M-l" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "@")))
    (global-set-key "\M-5" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "[")))
    (global-set-key "\M-6" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "]")))
    (global-set-key "\M-7" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "|")))
    (global-set-key "\M-/" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "\\")))
    (global-set-key "\M-8" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "{")))
    (global-set-key "\M-9" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "}")))
    (global-set-key "\M-n" '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "~")))))
```

Pros/Cons:

- (+) You keep the default bindings for mac cmd keys and meta emacs keys.
- (-) You obviously loose the default bindings for the remapped keys.
- (?) If your muscle memory makes you hit the keys by accident on an English keyboard, it still inserts the "correct/intended characters".

This was adopted form the [somewhat outdated information in emacswiki.org](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsOnGermanMac).

Comment: I'm using this too - One additional cons is that remapping does not work in Mini-Buffers like `C-x f`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emacs 22 configuration, that used to work just fine.

```
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil) 
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t) 
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```