# OSX Emacs: unbind just the right alt?

Tags: macos, emacs, dot-emacs, utf

I'm using [emacsformacosx.com](http://emacsformacosx.com) and would like to *stop* the Meta_R (right meta, or right option key) on my Apple keyboard from being an Emacs meta key.

The reason is that I want to be able to continue using the right option key as a character modifier so that I can enter UTF-8 chars when writing in emacs.  I know I can do a `C-x 8 RET` and type `em dash`, for example, but that's a lot more work than `Alt_R -`!

Is there some way of passing the keycode to `global-unset-key`?  Or something else I'm overlooking?

I should be clear that I still want to be able to use the Meta_L binding :)

Comment: Have you considered just using Command as meta?  That's the way I've run Emacs on my Mac for years - isn't it the default?  (I'm not aware of a way applications can distinguish one side from the other.)

Comment: I actually gave this a try after going with `(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil)` from an answer below.  I actually think having the Command key as Meta is more comfortable for me.  I added this to my .emacs: `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)`

Comment: Actually, the `C-x 8 RET` method you mentioned helped me solve this issue - combined with Helm it really rocks! I don't know these UTF8 character shortcuts anyway. Now I can place ☃ all around :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) has a variable called [ns-right-alternate-modifier](http://www.google.com/search?q=ns-right-alternate-modifier).  If I am reading the documentation correctly, this should do what you want:

```
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil)
```

I am unsure whether this is supported on stock GNU Emacs.

Comment: Perfect!  This is precisely the behaviour I was trying to achieve; thanks!

Comment: Well, using (setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil), alt doesn't work anymore with SHIFT. so: ALT+SHIFT+( —> 5 instead of —> [. :-/. Any idea ?

Comment: @PHF it works for me on mac with regular emacs distro.

Answer (score 27):

To map the the **left alt key with META** and the **right alt key with ALT**, on the Mac OS X version of GNU Emacs, I use:

```
(setq mac-option-key-is-meta t)
(setq mac-right-option-modifier nil)
```

It should do the job for the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for my macbook pro with french keyboard.

Considering that I hardly ever use the Fn key here what i did:

**; ALT is considered as ALT and not interpreted as META

(setq-default mac-option-modifier nil)**

**; Fn is considered as META and not interpreted as Fn

(setq-default mac-function-modifier 'meta)**

So I can fool around with as many backslash as I want in emacs!

\\[GREAT!!!]\\

Comment: Why FN and not left ctrl as META?

Comment: You do not map CMD to control?

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you want, but this is what I do and may help someone (for instance on the Macbook keyboard which has only one option key): You could bind just the keys you want:

```
(global-set-key "\M-_" (lambda () (interactive) (ucs-insert "2014")))
```

for em dash, etc. Just bind whatever you use commonly. In the rare case you want to type something you haven't bound, you can (in Aquamacs, and it should be possible in other Emacsen as well) hit `C-;` which is bound to `toggle-mac-option-modifier`, so that Option key is no longer Meta, type the character, and hit `C-;` again.